# LaTeX - How to make generated pdf properly copyable and keep the newlines?

Tags: compiling, font-encodings, white-space

The situation: I'm trying to generate my resume with Latex, and get a pdf with all the text - no problems here. When I copy all of this text into a plain .txt file though, the formatting transforms all whitespaces (newlines etc.) into a single space, it seems. For example, lists are not vertically placed anymore, but placed sequentially.

Does this maybe have something to do with how Latex files are built up (compiled) differently than ordinary text documents, causing it not to have any classical newlines characters, for example? In that case, would there be some way to insert those, allowing for a proper copy-and-paste functionality?

I tried to make use of the pachage `cmap`, which assists with Unicode mapping, but could not get it to work. Anyone who knows a fix to this, possibly with `cmap`, or possibly another package?

Comment: I don't think this is specific to LaTeX. If I recall correctly (no promises!) some software, such as Adobe Acrobat Pro (not just the Reader) can extract text using an OCR technique that preserves lines (optional) and interprets large space as tab (optional).

Comment: it is a general problem of PDF and PDF viewers, it is perhaps possible to force new lines with tagging and some clever uses of actualtext, but this is not yet tested, and quite probably the results will be different in different pdf viewers.